# UITableView scrolling doesnot scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uitabbar

I want to develop iOS app in which i am using transparent `Tababar`,

and having `UITableView` on `View` when i run my app, because of Transperant `Tababar` my `UITableView` gets behind `Tababar` and i am unable to select last row of `UITableView`.

See: [image]:
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: set your table view height upto your tabbar's starting position

Comment: I want tableView to go behind `tabbar`

Comment: you want tableview behind the tabbar and you also want to scroll upto last cell? how both are possible?

Comment: It might be possible because i have seen this in many apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple adjust

```
  table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 200, 0); // try setting this value
```

hope this helps u :)

Comment: It works but i didn't understand. why u set width to 200 and height got changed ?

Comment: no the tableview's height remains same but content's height is changed check out "contentInset" property by this u can scroll to 200 pts above from bottom and there by u can select the last cell and one thing adjust it some required value :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the tab bar alpha that's the issue. It't the frame of the UITableView. Either set the frame of the table to take the tab bar into account, or:

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Edit, potentially iOS7 having edge to edge layout. Try in `viewDidLoad` (self refers to the controller):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)]) {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }
```

Comment: dude i wrote in `viewDidLoad` but didn't help.

Comment: Ah, ok,. Try the edit if you're not happy with the manner of your fix. I'd personally consider the inset solution to be slightly hacky since the frame of the table view is still below your tab bar.

Comment: Ah, just seen you want the table to be behind the tab bar! Going to leave that up in case it helps someone else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possiblities:-

1). Firstly, You might have forgot to set datasource and delegate of the tableview to self.

2). The frame might be assigned incorrectly, i.e when we use both navigationbar and tab bar the height of tableView in iPhone4 is 367 and in iPhone5 it is 455.

Comment: yes, i have connected to datasource and delegate. size of the tableview is `320 * 480`