# Bottom of Table View (Cell) cut off

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

There's more content in my `Table View`, but this **cell is getting cut off and not showing more content**:

[image]

... So I'm not able to scroll any more, even there is more content.

If I pull up with my finger it shows more content, but then when I let my finger off the cell it goes back to the state show in the image above.

*I've tried making sure I set height and width in the `Labels` and `Images` in AutoLayout since I thought that might be a problem, but still hasn't fixed it.*

Any ideas?  Thanks!

**UPDATE - Table View structure in Storyboard**
[image]

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[DBase self]]) {
        return 520;
    }
    else {
        return tableView.rowHeight; // return the default height
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try by setting contentInset like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634467/uitableview-scrolling-doesnot-scroll/19635540#19635540

Comment: @Shan thanks for the response!  I put `    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it didn't help, was I supposed to put it somewhere else?

Comment: no u can't  make all values to zero it don't effect as i answered give bottom value to 100 or above according to your cell height for example put this in viewDidLoad ` table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 200, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding height and width constraints to your UITableViewContoller or UITableView in the storyboard.main.

Depending on the size of your device, the UITableView size will remain constant unless you set constraints that will work across all devices.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Just wondering how you would go about doing that?  I've thought about pinning the sides, but that option doesn't seem available at the Table View Controller or Table View or Custom Table View Cell level.

Comment: Well is your tableview in view controller is it just a straight forward uitableviewcontroller? And is (the answer to the previous question) created programmatically or in the storyboard?

Comment: Added an image above of the storyboard structure.  Also added the only code that affects the cells, which is the `height` code, where DBase is `YourAPICell2` custom cell, and `else` is all other `APICell`s.

Comment: Okay I see it now. So try adding constraints from the storyboard. It should be in the 2 icon from the bottom right in the main Xcode screen. Set the height and width to 0 and you should be good

Comment: Which level should I be on: Table View Controller or Table View or Custom Table View Cell?  Because it seems to not letting me actually set it on any of them.  I can't click the Height or Width box.

Comment: Added another image in my Question, because I can't actually click on the Height or Width box.  Any ideas?

Comment: Wow um i guess you can't do it like that. Try re-creating that same view with a tableview inside a uiviewcontroller and use uitableviewdelegate and uitableviewdatasource. I do think there might be something wrong with the height of those cells though

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem as well but mine was only cutting off a single cell. I solved it and thought I'd post this here as it may help others in the future

I was using custom cells created from nibs. Some of my cells could change heights so I was also using this:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 61
```

I figured out the issue was that I was setting top, left, right and height constraints on my view. I needed to set the bottom constraint as well or else my row height would be way smaller than it should be.

So if you are having this problem check if your row heights aren't smaller than the views that they contain.